# SQL複数の値をかえす方法

Tags: sql

下記のような二つのテーブルがあり、SQLで希望する出力結果を出すにはどのようなコードが必要でしょうか。

TableA as a
取引ID, 購入者国ID, 販売者国ID
xxxx, 101, 201
yyyy, 301, 201
・
・
・

TableB as b
国ID, 国名前
101, Japan
201, USA
301, UK
・
・
・

希望する出力結果
取引ID, 購入者国名, 販売者国名

一つの値のみJoinで結合する方法はわかるのですが、
二つ以上になる場合はどのようなコードになるのでしょうか。

```
Select
a.取引ID,b.国名前 as 購入者国名, (???????) as 販売者国名
from TableA as a
INNER JOIN TableB as b
ON a.取引ID = b.国名前
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

購入者国で国名テーブルを結合するのと同様に
販売者国でも国名テーブルを結合しましょう

あと質問中の結合の条件も間違っているようです。
条件としては（購入or取引）者国IDと一致する国IDを紐づけないきゃいけないですね。

```
Select
a.取引ID,b1.国名前 as 購入者国名, b2.国名前 as 販売者国名
from TableA as a
INNER JOIN TableB as b1 ON a.購入者国ID = b1.国ID
INNER JOIN TableB as b2 ON a.取引者国ID = b2.国ID
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！試してみます。